# Ignore "imported and not used" compile-time error

Tags: go

I get this error:

> src/huru/utils/utils.go:6:2: imported and not used: "fmt"
>
> src/huru/utils/utils.go:9:2: imported and not used: "net/http"

when I have these unused imports:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)
```

> `<rant>` it turns out this a rather seriously annoying "feature" because
>   some IDEs  like VSCode will automatically remove unused imports which
>   is f*cking annoying when you are about type the characters that will
>   use the imports but you hit save first or what not. `</rant>`

Is there a way to ignore this compile error with a command line option?
something like:

```
go install main --ignore-dumb-errors
```

Comment: In Go you have to use imports, or not to declare them at all. It's not a dumb error, it's how Go as language behaves. Love it or leave it.

Comment: no. it is by design.

Comment: Go is such a wonderful language lulz

Comment: Why on earth would it matter if there are unused imports, the compiler should just erase them then, who cares? Just add a warning and compile anyway.

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman: By design, the Go compiler doesn't have warnings.

Comment: The authors decided to make this an error to keep compile times small. It is actually really useful for large codebases. It's a lesson learned from C and C++. For the same reason circular imports are disallowed. Most IDEs and editors can manage imports automatically, either natively or by integrating [goimports](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports), do this really isn't a problem in practice.

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#unused_variables_and_imports

Answer (score 2):

> [Install additional tools](https://golang.org/doc/install/source#tools)
>
> The source code for several Go tools (including goimports) is kept in the
>   go.tools repository. To install all of them, run the go get command:
>
> ```
> $ go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/...
> ```
>
> Or if you just want to install a specific command (goimports in this
>   case):
>
> ```
> $ go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports
> ```
>
> To install these tools, the go get command requires that Git be
>   installed locally.
>
> You must also have a workspace (GOPATH) set up; see [How to Write Go
>   Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) for the details.

---

```
$ goimports -help
usage: goimports [flags] [path ...]
  -cpuprofile string
        CPU profile output
  -d    display diffs instead of rewriting files
  -e    report all errors (not just the first 10 on different lines)
  -l    list files whose formatting differs from goimport's
  -local string
        put imports beginning with this string after 3rd-party packages; comma-separated list
  -memprofile string
        memory profile output
  -memrate int
        if > 0, sets runtime.MemProfileRate
  -srcdir dir
        choose imports as if source code is from dir. When operating on a single file, dir may instead be the complete file name.
  -trace string
        trace profile output
  -v    verbose logging
  -w    write result to (source) file instead of stdout
$
```

---

Run the `goimports` command with flag `-w` on your source code. It will fix your imports for you. It's how the Go Playground and IDEs fix imports.

---

For example,

```
$ cat imports.go
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}

$ goimports -w imports.go
$ cat imports.go
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
$
```

You can run it on an entire directory too.